# struct field marshaling failed on linux

Tags: .net-core, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm using following struct for data marshaling with PInvoke

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Data
{
  int id;
  IntPtr state;
  object obj;
}
```

And all works fine on Windows, but on Linux I'm getting the error:

> Cannot marshal field 'obj' of type 'Data': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Marshaling to and from COM interface pointers isn't supported).

Why?
Is it possible to disable marshaling for the specific field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging the CLR sources I've found that the issue is really Linux specific, and tied to COM interop feature, which is windows-only.

So I've fixed the problem using IntPtr for obj (as @Simonare suggested) and GCHandle.

Answer (score 0):

`object obj;` property is invalid

You can try with `IntPtr obj;`

What is the actual type of `obj`?

Comment: why is that ? `obj` must be a managed reference type (or compatible)

Comment: please check this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues/433)

Comment: those guys just commented the declaration to get rid of the error, so-so solution)